# How do I compare two separate sets of xy coordinates of varying length?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two different sets of x-y coordinates that I want to compare. The sets are not the same size, but I would like to calculate some type of similarity index between the two.

Example:

```
    Set1 = [(1,2), (3,6), (7,8)] 
    Set2 = [(2,2), (3,5)]
```

The goal of the metric/algorithm I’m looking for is to evaluate the “accuracy” of a prediction algorithm in finding points relative to a known ground truth set of points.

I have tried taking the minimum distance of ground truth points relative to the closest predicted point, but that as a metric fails to quantify/penalize errors of over-prediction.

[Example Scatter plot of two data sets I want to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZcQp.png)

Comment: What's your expected output from the example?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing the domain. E.g. "everything that is out of a unit radius doesn't make sense" or "penalize proportionally to inverse distance" will result in two different measures of similarity

Comment: @DanW, A single numerical representation of "accuracy" in some sense of the word. While it doesn't have to be on a scale of 0 to 100%, I am looking for something that can tell me the relative distance of a set to the ground truth. if Set1 is ground truth, I want to know that Set2 is some X distance away, while a 3rd set (Set3) is less "accurate" because it is at Y distance and Y > X.

Comment: Is this even a programming question, or a mathematics one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Estimate density of ground truth and prediction datasets using your kernel of choice. Which kernel to choose depends on the domain; box kernel or RBF might be a reasonable choice.
2. Calculate the divergence between these densities. The notion of divergence is again up to you, mean squared distance or KL divergence might work.

Implementation using box kernel and mean squares:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

# constants: don't forget to replace with your own values
x_width, y_width = 10, 10
kernel_width = 3

gt_field = np.zeros((x_width, y_width))
prediction_field = gt_field.copy()
# split Set1 into two lists of x and y coordinates
# then set these points to 1
gt_field[list(zip(*Set1))] = 1
prediction_field[list(zip(*Set2))] = 1

# using box kernel as the simplest one
kernel = np.ones((kernel_width, kernel_width)) / kernel_width ** 2

# apply kernel - now we have densities
gt_field = convolve2d(gt_field, kernel)
prediction_field = convolve2d(prediction_field, kernel)

# calculate mean squared error
mse = ((gt_field - prediction_field) ** 2).mean()
```

I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way to implement it, but even this should work for few hundred points as on the example picture.